# Python equivalent of SetConstant ( Eigen )

Tags: python, numpy, class, matrix, eigen

What is the meaning of set.constant ?
I have a program that i need to write in python without using creating a new class. Is there an equivalent of it in python or numpy specifically ?

Comment: Eigen neither has `set.constant` nor `SetConstant`. There is a set of [`setConstant`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac2f1e50d1f567da38da1d2f07c5ab559) member functions which sets all elements of a Matrix or Array to the given value.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesnt use constants.

To use a variable outside the current scope you can use:

```
global var
var =
```